# List population dependency on other function choice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a pretty basic little script with choices of up to 3 products, which will result in a price depending on whether summer or winter is chosen as season.

I've got it working as a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lantador/4chc7nkd/

My problem is I would like to make the list of products (productchoice), change which products are listed (ie., 2 different listes) depending on which season I pick - but I am very unsure on how to approach that?

The script:

```
$(function product() {
  var productchoice = {
    "No choice": "0",
    "Apples": "10.8",
    "Bananas": "17.2",
    "Cookies": "6.5",
    "Icecream": "10.8",
    "Lollipops": "6.5"
  };

  function populate(options) {
    var product_container = ""
    $.each(options, function(key, value) {
      product_container += '<option value="' + value + '">' + key + '</option>'
    });
    $(".product").each(function() {
      $(this).html(product_container);
      // this.innerHTML = container;
    });
  }

  $(".product").on("change", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.product').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('.seasontype').each(function() {
      total *= parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2) + ' dollahbats');
  });

  populate(productchoice);
});




$(function seasontype() {
  var ktypevalg = {
    "Winter": "0.5",
    "Summer": "1.0",
  };

  function populate(options) {
    var ktype_container = ""
    $.each(options, function(key, value) {
      ktype_container += '<option value="' + value + '">' + key + '</option>'
    });
    $(".seasontype").each(function() {
      $(this).html(ktype_container);
      // this.innerHTML = container;
    });
  }

  $(".seasontype").on("change", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.fag').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('.seasontype').each(function() {
      total *= parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2) + ' dollahbats');
  });

  populate(ktypevalg);
});
```

The HTML:

```
  <center>
<br>3 options with different choices from a list:
<p>Choice 1:
    <select class="product" id="product1"></select>
</p>
<p>Choice 2:
    <select class="product" id="product2"></select>
</p>
<p>Choice 3:
    <select class="product" id="product3"></select>
</p>
<p>Total price: <span id="total">0.00 dollahbats</span>

</p>
<p>Season:
    <select class="seasontype" id="ktype1"></select>
</p>
    </center>

<br/>
```

Comment: you have `$(".seasontype").on("change", function () {` handler, can't you call `populate` from there with different set of products?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your products list:

```
var productchoice = {
    "No choice":
            {
                price: "0",
                winter: 1, //show in winter list
                summer: 1  //show in summer list
            }
    ,
    "Apples": {
        price: "10.8",
        winter: 0,  //do not show in winter list
        summer: 1   //show in summer list
    }
    //... and so on
};
```

Then in your each iteration you need to check, what is the season and create a condition, is this product available in that season:

```
var product_container = '';
$.each(options, function (key, value) {
    if (($('#ktype1').val() == '0.5' && value.winter == 1) || ($('#ktype1').val() == '1.0' && value.summer == 1)) {
        product_container += '<option value="' + value.price + '">' + key + '</option>'
    }
});
```